# AWSSignInProvider for OpenID using Mobile Hub

Tags: amazon-web-services, xcode7, openid

I have an iOS 7 app that uses AWS Mobile Hub for AWS services. I am using Auth0 as an identity broker. All of my users authenticate using OpenID.

In order to use Mobile Hub I have to define an AWSSignInProvider for Auth0 users. Has anyone written a (possibly generic?) AWSSignInProvider in Objective C for OpenID users? I have written one but it does not work correctly. It works for the initial login but does not refresh the Auth0 login for Auth0 users when they re-login to my app.

My code is below. It does not work right.

Thanks

Auth0SignInProvider.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Lock/Lock.h>
#import "AWSSignInProvider.h"

@class FFKeyChain;

#pragma clang assume_nonnull begin
@interface FFAuth0SignInProvider : NSObject <AWSSignInProvider>

@property (readonly, strong) FFKeyChain *                               keychain;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (void)completeLogin;

@end
#pragma clang assume_nonnull end
```

Auth0SignInProvider.m

```
#import "Auth0SignInProvider.h"
#import <Lock/Lock.h>
#import "AWSIdentityManager.h"
#import "AWSConfiguration.h"
#import "Cloud.h"
#import "FFCloudController.h"
#import "FFJWT.h"
#import "FFKeyChain.h"

static NSString *const AWSAuth0SignInProviderKey = @"Auth0";
static NSString *const AWSAuth0SignInProviderUserNameKey = @"Auth0.userName";
static NSString *const AWSAuth0SignInProviderImageURLKey = @"Auth0.imageURL";
static NSTimeInterval const AWSAuth0SignInProviderTokenRefreshBuffer = 10 * 60;

@interface AWSIdentityManager()

- (void)completeLogin;

@end

@interface FFAuth0SignInProvider()

@property (atomic, strong) AWSTaskCompletionSource *taskCompletionSource;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;

@end

@implementation FFAuth0SignInProvider

@synthesize keychain=_keychain;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static FFAuth0SignInProvider *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    //ok1
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [FFAuth0SignInProvider new];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _keychain = [FFKeyChain sharedInstance];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Properties

- (FFKeyChain*)keychain
{
    if (!_keychain)
    {
        _keychain = [FFKeyChain sharedInstance];
    }

    return _keychain;
}

#pragma mark - AWSIdentityProvider Protocol

- (NSString *)identityProviderName
{
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary][STRAuth0DomainKey];
}

- (AWSTask<NSString *> *)token
{
    NSString* tokenString = [[self keychain] stringForKey:UDAuth0IdToken];
    NSString* refreshToken = [[self keychain] stringForKey:UDAuth0RefreshToken];
    NSDate* idTokenExpirationDate = [[[FFJWT alloc] initWithToken:tokenString] expDate];

    if (tokenString
        // If the cached token expires within 10 min, tries refreshing a token.
        && [idTokenExpirationDate compare:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:AWSAuth0SignInProviderTokenRefreshBuffer]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        return [AWSTask taskWithResult:tokenString];
    }

    AWSTaskCompletionSource *taskCompletionSource = [AWSTaskCompletionSource taskCompletionSource];
    A0Lock* lock = [A0Lock sharedLock];
    A0APIClient* client = [lock apiClient];
    A0AuthParameters* params = [A0AuthParameters newDefaultParams];
    params[A0ParameterConnection] = [[FFCloudController sharedInstance] auth0ConnectionName:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:UDLoginType]];
    [client fetchNewIdTokenWithRefreshToken:refreshToken parameters:params success:^(A0Token * _Nonnull token)
    {
        NSLog(@"Success - token");

        [[self keychain] setString:token.idToken ForKey:UDAuth0IdToken];
        taskCompletionSource.result = token.idToken;

    } failure:^(NSError * _Nonnull error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error - token: %@", error);

        taskCompletionSource.error = error;
    }];

    return taskCompletionSource.task;
}

- (BOOL)isLoggedIn {
    NSData* profile = [[self keychain] dataForKey:UDAuth0Profile];
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderKey] != nil && (profile != nil);
}

- (NSString *)userName {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderUserNameKey];
}

- (void)setUserName:(NSString *)userName {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userName
                                              forKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderUserNameKey];
}

- (NSURL *)imageURL {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderImageURLKey]];
}

- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageURL.absoluteString
                                              forKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderImageURLKey];
}

- (void)reloadSession {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderKey]
        && [[self keychain] stringForKey:UDAuth0IdToken])
    {
        [self completeLogin];
    }
}

- (void)completeLogin {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES"
                                              forKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[AWSIdentityManager sharedInstance] completeLogin];

    A0UserProfile *profile = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[self keychain] dataForKey:UDAuth0Profile]];
    self.userName = profile.email;
}

- (void)login
{
    if ([[self keychain] stringForKey:UDAuth0IdToken])
    {
        [self completeLogin];
        return;
    }

    A0AuthParameters* params = [A0AuthParameters newDefaultParams];
    params[A0ParameterConnection] = [[FFCloudController sharedInstance] auth0ConnectionName:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:UDLoginType]];

    [[[A0Lock sharedLock] apiClient] loginWithUsername:[[FFKeyChain sharedInstance] stringForKey:UDEmail] password:[[FFKeyChain sharedInstance] stringForKey:UDPassword] parameters:params success:^(A0UserProfile * _Nonnull profile, A0Token * _Nonnull tokenInfo)
    {
        [[self keychain] setString:tokenInfo.idToken ForKey:UDAuth0IdToken];
        [[self keychain] setString:tokenInfo.refreshToken ForKey:UDAuth0RefreshToken];
        [[self keychain] setData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:profile] ForKey:UDAuth0Profile];

        [self completeLogin];

    } failure:^(NSError * _Nonnull error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Auth0 login error: %@", error);
    }];
}

- (void)logout
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:AWSAuth0SignInProviderKey];
    [[self keychain] removeObjectForKey:UDAuth0IdToken];
    [[self keychain] removeObjectForKey:UDAuth0AccessToken];
    [[self keychain] removeObjectForKey:UDAuth0RefreshToken];
    [[self keychain] removeObjectForKey:UDAuth0Profile];
    [[[A0Lock sharedLock] apiClient] logout];
}

#pragma mark - Application delegates

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[A0Lock sharedLock] handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It will only attempt to get an updated logins map if the credentials associated with the CredentialsProvider have expired.  Have you tried calling [clearCredentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/clearCredentials) on the CredentialsProvider when you log out to force it to refresh?